# errors loading hunchentoot in windows environment

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I got back to a project which I postponed – it was rest service written  in common lisp. I had no problem running the project a couple of months ago when I used **sbcl 1.3.12**. The first problems appeared after updating `sbcl` to version **1.3.18**. I couldn’t start **Hunchentoot**, so I went back to `sbcl` **1.3.12** and the problem was resolved. However it was a couple of months ago.

Today I can’t run Huchentoot nor compile a project which uses its packages, it doesn’t matter which version of `sbcl` I use – **1.3.12** or **1.4.2** – I think that the version of Hunchentoot available via quicklisp has changed.
A compilation of the project returns an error:

```
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;   
;     Symbol "EASY-ACCEPTOR" not found in the HUNCHENTOOT package.
;
```

Now I cannot even start Hunchentoot server. It doesn’t matter if I use `sbcl` or `clozurecl`:

```
? (hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 4242))
> Error: Reader error: No external symbol named "START" in package #<Package "HUNCHENTOOT"> .
> While executing: CCL::%PARSE-TOKEN, in process listener(1).

> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Use the internal symbol HUNCHENTOOT::START
> Type :? for other options.
```

I tried `(use-package 'hunchentoot')` but it didn’t help.

Although *I don’t have such problems in Linux environment*, but I got used to working in windows and I would like to fix it.

Is it possible or should I forget about using **Windows** with common lisp?

Comment: I guess that your local system versions or files got messed up.  I heard that you can solve many problems under Windows by restarting, rebooting, reinstalling — maybe clean and reinstall Quicklisp?

Comment: Have you tried doing `(asdf:load-system :hunchentoot :force t)`?

Comment: I tried (ql:update-all-dists). Also (asdf:load-system :hunchentoot :force t) doesn’t help.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of Hunchentoot and then repeated (asdf:load-system :hunchentoot :force t) and now it works. Thank you. However, have you any idea how to solve the problem I could run Hunchentoot using quicklisp?

Comment: Now it works also via quicklisp. Thank you very much!